# Fatal error: Call to a member function rowCount() on boolean

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Olá,

Sou iniciante em conexões PDO no PHP e no meu primeiro `select` estou enfrentando o seguinte erro:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function rowCount() on boolean in C:\MAMP\htdocs\samples\pdo\conexao.php on line 12
```

Segue meu código:

```
<?php
    try {
        $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dname=dashboard","root","root");
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo '<b style="color:red">'.$e->getMessage().'</b>';
    }

    $buscarUsuario = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM usuarios");

    $buscarUsuario->rowCount(); //linha 12
```

Verifiquei a conexão e também o nome da tabela, não tem nada de errado, procurei possiveis soluções para este meu problema aqui no forum e nada que resolvesse, e ao dar `var_dump` nos usuários, ele me retorna `bool(false)`.

Comment: Se por acaso a query não for executada, `$pdo->query()` retorna um `boolean == false`

Comment: Adicione `$buscarUsuario = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM usuarios");` dentro do `try {` e faça `if($buscarUsuario){ $buscarUsuario->rowCount(); }`

Comment: @MarceloBoni mas a query nao esta sendo executada??

Comment: Se tivesse sido executada, não retornaria bool(false), faça o que recomendei e veja qual o erro dado na query